# Qt window moves even when intercepting mouse events

Tags: linux, qt, kde-plasma, qtopengl

I have a Qt OpenGL (with qt 5.5)  Application in which you can click to drag objects in a 3D scene.

This is implemented by having a subclass of `QOpenGLWidget` which overrides  `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`.

However, when I drag an object, I can move it for one frame before the window starts activating the window move mode, and my mouse movements actually start moving the whole window, as if I was dragging the title bar.

I suspect there is a conflict between the application and my window manager (kwin 5.4.3), but I don't know where to look at to debug this issue and whether it's my application's fault or if I have to fix my window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to call the `accept()` method of the event you are handling.